# RESideMenu show selected item

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I'm using this for the menu in my app: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu and I want to be able to show the selected item in order to make it more clear which view the user is currently on. Would I be able to do this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RESideMenu` controller is a container controller like `UITabBarController` or `UISplitViewController`. That means that you specify content view controllers (in case of `RESideMenu`: `content` (front), `right menu` and `left menu` view controllers) and let container controller handle their display in a way that controller wants. That means that you can track which view controller you supplied to RESideMenu and highlight your cells depending on that information.

For example, you can associate a view controller instance with each menu cell and then:

```
if (cellBackingObject.viewController == reSideMenu.contentViewController)
{
    // highlight cell
}
else
{
    // don't highlight cell
}
```

Note, that you should reasonably manage view controller's life, because storing all of them in memory is not always good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where would that if statement go?

Comment: @Jacob in your configure cell code(-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).